# Did many (really necessary) edits, but most of them not approved (or not reviewed)

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

I did many many good edits in past several hours. But, it seems like most of them are not approved or like even not peer-reviewed.

I have seen my  [suggestion tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3830694/krupal-shah?tab=activity&sort=suggestions&page=1) and [revision tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3830694/krupal-shah?tab=activity&sort=revisions). Only 60% of the edits are revised. I think they were really necessary edits and don't think anyone would disapprove that...I think they are not even peer-reviewed.

And one more question I have is:

Can I see if my edits are pending for approval or if they got approved or not? (like in flags (i.e active, helpful etc.))

Comment: There is currently no way, though I think it would be useful. On a related note please stop using code-markup (back ticks) for things that aren't code. A language name is not code and can just be written normally.

Comment: @Ben yes, indeed it would be "very useful". and sorry for code markups, I have edited the question.

Comment: A lot of them are minor, converting things like "PLZ LOOK AT MI CODE, I NEED UR HELP" to "plz look at mi code, i need ur help" are not improvements.

For the most part, it seems the Community bot is rejecting them, essentially its rejecting your edit because another one has happened before yours has been reviewed. We do need more specific examples if you have something you want us to review though

Comment: @Joe Not exactly. Community rejects edits because one of the reviewers clicks the "Improve" button and unchecks the "this edit was helpful" box. That usually happens when the suggested edit does not fix one or more glaring problems in the post, and the reviewer decides to go ahead and fix these while he's looking at it.

Comment: @CodyGray ahh, thanks, I knew it was something like that, but not sure on the exact details.

Comment: Your most recent edits look pretty good; keep up the good work.  Take note of any useful feedback you get.  For example, on [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5559248), your edit description should have been "Moved code from pastebin to question," not "Improved formatting."

Comment: @RobertHarvey thank you so much for guiding and appreciating...Next time, I will try to provide more and specific details in my 'Edit Summary'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked through your edits, and most of them were very useful. Keep that going: most of the edits we get in the Suggested Edits queue are *terrible* (and that's putting it lightly).

In fact, most of them were *unanimously approved*. That is, no one voted to reject them, which is rare. In my cursory glance, I only saw one that was rejected, and it was only because the system auto-rejected it after someone with editing privileges revised the post before your edit was approved.

If someone with over 2k reputation edits the question while your suggested edit is pending approval, the Community user will automatically reject your edit unless someone edited from the Suggested Edits review queue and marked your edit as helpful (in which case the Community user will  automatically approve your edit).

The only thing I would suggest would be to make your edit summaries a little bit clearer: they are very important because they let the reviewers know what the point of your edit was and they become part of a  post's revision history if your edit is approved.

If you want to see the results of your suggested edits, you can go to the [suggestions subset of your activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions&page=1) (this link will point anyone who clicks on it to *their own* history). From there, you can click on the "suggested edit" hyperlink to see the status of your edit in real-time:

[image: Suggested edits]

If your edit is approved, you can also view who, if anyone, voted to reject it and for what reason from the revision history of a post:

[image: Get to queue from revision history]

Comment: thank u so much..I will remember your suggestions...Also, I amazed about how you created this gif image......:-)thanks anyway.

Comment: @krupalshah You're welcome: keep up the good edits! I used a tool called [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) to create the GIF.

Comment: @AstroCB `Edits where all users approve the edit are rare`, really? Many of my own edits have all three users approving them, must mean I'm pretty good at editing then.

Comment: @cybermonkey It does; major changes have been made to the edit reasons since this posting that have resulted in more unanimous approvals or rejections, but it still stands that people have widely differing opinions about what constitutes an acceptable edit, so you should be proud of that.